# Apache2 on Ubuntu 12.04 -- DirectoryIndex ignored

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu-12.04, directoryindex

I have a relatively fresh installation of LAMP on Ubuntu 12.04 (installed using tasksel). I've got a virtual host pointed at a development project in my home directory containing plain Hello World index.html. Apache is showing the directory index instead of displaying the index.html. The [PDF here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CGIQFjAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fhelp.ubuntu.com%2F12.04%2Fserverguide%2Fserverguide.pdf&ei=vdbxT_fxD43VrQGesfTNDQ&usg=AFQjCNFd4boLCsAgAJV_TZl7BHg54QGs2Q&sig2=wVxX7u7t75XOQWXa3sgeJw)(page 190) says that the default DirectoryIndex is in /etc/apache2/mods-available/dir.conf, which I've confirmed, and mod_dir is enabled.

DirectoryIndex works inside a .htaccess in the project root directory, but I'd like to have it set up server-wide. I'm probably missing something simple.

Comment: You probably done something wrong, Apache display index.html instead of the directory by default. Did you already changed somethin in it ?

Answer (score 1):

Don't mess with apache configuration files unless you know what you're doing.

If you want to edit the Apache2 default site edit `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default` add to the VirtualHost section the name(s) of the file you want apache to search, more info at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_dir.html
ex:

```
    DirectoryIndex  lookforme-first.html lookforme-next.php
```

afterward reload apache with `sudo service apache2 reload`.